# Semantic UI with angular js

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-angular

we are working on a new project and unable to decide between angular material or semantic ui.

We already used angular material and know its a good combination.

But we are new to semantic and our customer is interested in its ui. But before using it with angular, want to know if we would face any problems.

For example, md-autocomplete is one such thing. md-autocomplete in angular material is very useful.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in their [documentation](http://semantic-ui.com/introduction/integrations.html#contribute-to-angular-development) (at the bottom of the page). Angular integration is still in development, you will have to see for yourself if your needs are met.